Why is Hmmlearn giving me a pybind11 GIL state error?
I am trying to use hmmlearn's hidden markov models in my jupyter notebook. No matter how I try to interact with it, I get the same runtime error (which I don't understand and can't find any information on why it's happening). Here is an example of my code:
Code
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=100)
model.startprob_ = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
model.transmat_ = np.array([[0.6, 0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.4, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]])
model.emissionprob_ = np.array([[0.6, 0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.4, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]])

data = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
observations = np.array(data).reshape(-1, 1)
model.fit(observations)
hidden_states = model.predict(observations)

Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 8
      6 data = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
      7 observations = np.array(data).reshape(-1, 1)
----> 8 model.fit(observations)
      9 hidden_states = model.predict(observations)

File ~/Documents/NTNU/9sem/masters/masters-prep-project/.conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hmmlearn/base.py:485, in _AbstractHMM.fit(self, X, lengths)
    482 self.monitor_._reset()
    484 for iter in range(self.n_iter):
--> 485     stats, curr_logprob = self._do_estep(X, lengths)
    487     # Compute lower bound before updating model parameters
    488     lower_bound = self._compute_lower_bound(curr_logprob)

File ~/Documents/NTNU/9sem/masters/masters-prep-project/.conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hmmlearn/base.py:764, in _AbstractHMM._do_estep(self, X, lengths)
    762 curr_logprob = 0
    763 for sub_X in _utils.split_X_lengths(X, lengths):
--> 764     lattice, logprob, posteriors, fwdlattice, bwdlattice = impl(sub_X)
    765     # Derived HMM classes will implement the following method to
    766     # update their probability distributions, so keep
    767     # a single call to this method for simplicity.
    768     self._accumulate_sufficient_statistics(
    769         stats, sub_X, lattice, posteriors, fwdlattice,
    770         bwdlattice)
...
    886     bwdlattice = _hmmc.backward_log(
    887         self.startprob_, self.transmat_, log_frameprob)
    888     posteriors = self._compute_posteriors_log(fwdlattice, bwdlattice)

RuntimeError: pybind11::handle::inc_ref() PyGILState_Check() failure.

I can't find anything helpful about this pybind11 error.
What I have tried

Changing python version (3.11, 3.10 and 3.9)
Creating a new conda env
Reinstalling packages
Making sure packages are up to date

What am I trying to do?
I am trying to implement an unsupervised HMM to view the clustering of my data.

Just checked your code, it works on MacOs for Python 3.11.6 with hmmlearn==0.3.2.

@JohnnyCheesecutter yes, that's what I've tried running on as well. Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?
